# Why are web part connections in a template breaking?

Tags: 2010, web-part, site-template, reporting-services, connected-web-parts

We have a SharePoint site that we created based on a blank site template.
We add lists, pages, webparts (including some connected web parts) and then save this site as a template (.wsp file).

We create a new site collection, and apply this template to the root web site in the collection.
This is working fine, except the web part connections are breaking and need to be manually re-established.

The web parts are a "producer" (our custom web part that reads a parameter from a SharePoint list and sends the output) and the consumer (SSRS Report Viewer web part) that takes the value from the producer part and uses it as a report parameter.

What we have noticed is that the custom (producer) web part ID value stays the same for each site we apply the template to, but the SSRS Web Part IDs change for every site.

The template page has the producerID and consumerIDs statically set in the template, so this is what is causing the connection to break and need to be re-established.

Any ideas on why just the SSRS web part is getting a new ID each time and not the other web parts?

This is what the code in the page looks like. The ID in the SQL Server Reporting Services Report Viewer web part is changing when the page is deployed as part of a site template:

```
<SPWebPartConnections>
<WebPartPages:SPWebPartConnection ConsumerConnectionPointID="ReportParameters" ConsumerID="g_172ac89a_1639_4c78_a0ce_594d5a6260a0" ID="c1588345187" ProviderConnectionPointID="ITransformableFilterValues" ProviderID="g_bc912b65_41ff_4a6e_b447_41ec7ca95eb6">
<WebPartPages:TransformableFilterValuesToFilterValuesTransformer MappedConsumerParameterName="projectID">
</WebPartPages:TransformableFilterValuesToFilterValuesTransformer>
</WebPartPages:SPWebPartConnection>
</SPWebPartConnections>

...

<WpNs1:ReportViewerWebPart runat="server" __MarkupType="xmlmarkup" WebPart="true" __WebPartId="{172AC89A-1639-4C78-A0CE-594D5A6260A0}" >
...
<ID>g_172ac89a_1639_4c78_a0ce_594d5a6260a0</ID>
<Title>SQL Server Reporting Services Report Viewer</Title>
...
```

Answer (score 1):

Technet possible solutions:

**UpdateMode to Conditional**

*Preferred if it works*

- http://social.technet.microsoft.com/Forums/br/sharepoint2010general/thread/a5a3c250-ea34-4c01-83e9-4574fc8ab621

Conclusion: set the updatepanels UpdateMode to Conditional (in master page and current page)

**Code behind to set the new WebPartId in the connection**

- http://social.technet.microsoft.com/Forums/en-CA/sharepointgeneralprevious/thread/8d98206d-b41f-4ee4-b537-a4bf5cec0434

Conclusion: Import the wsp into visual studio and use code behind during the onsiteprovisioning event

- programmatically get the new web part id
- set that property in the connection